# Why is For loop solution different from .Every() solution?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is for the FreeCodeCamp challenge: "Wherefore art thou". The challenge ask to "make a function that looks through an array of objects (first argument) and returns an array of all objects that have matching property and value pairs (second argument)."

I had to check out the solutions in order to understand how it works. I also made my own solution with **For** loop to see if it works as well too.

Using this argument/array: "`whatIsInAName([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 })`" which should return "`[{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }]`", it seems that .Every() method will only work.

.Every method

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  // What's in a name?
  var arr = [];
  // Only change code below this line
  var myCol = collection;
  var mySou = Object.keys(source);
  
  arr =  myCol.filter(function(object){
    return mySou.every(function(key){
      return object.hasOwnProperty(key) && object[key] === source[key];
      
    }
    );
  });
  
  // Only change code above this line
  return arr;
}

console.log(whatIsInAName([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**For** loop method

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  // What's in a name?
  var arr = [];
  // Only change code below this line
  var myCol = collection;
  var mySou = Object.keys(source);
  
  arr =  myCol.filter(function(object){
    
      for (var i = 0; i < mySou.length; i++) {
        return object.hasOwnProperty(mySou[i]) && object[mySou[i]] === source[mySou[i]];
        
    }
    
  });
  
  // Only change code above this line
  return arr;
}

console.log(whatIsInAName([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Two questions. Is it possible for the **For** loop method to work? If yes, then how do I get it to work to return only "`[{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }]`"

Comment: return in a for loop returns from the enclosing function, therefore your for loop will execute exactly once ... `every` iterates while the return value is truthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two conditions in the filter function as follows in order for it work properly:

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  // What's in a name?
  var arr = [];
  // Only change code below this line
  var myCol = collection;
  var mySou = Object.keys(source);

  arr =  myCol.filter(function(object){

      for (var i = 0; i < mySou.length; i++) {
        if(!(object.hasOwnProperty(mySou[i]) && object[mySou[i]] === source[mySou[i]])){
            return false;         # if any key value pair in the source doesn't exist in 
                                  # object, return false
        };
    }
    return true;   # if all key value pairs in the source can be found in the object return true
  });

  // Only change code above this line
  return arr;
}

whatIsInAName([{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 1 }, { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2 }], { "a": 1, "b": 2 })
# [ { a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b: 2, c: 2 } ]
```

Comment: Dang. I've seen this solution in another article. I was hoping to make my own unique solution. But thanks for your help.